# How does appeal against sending off work in football?

Tags: rules, football

Taking a recent example of two unsuccessful appeals by Real Madrid:
1. Sergio Ramos being sent off against Deportivo.
2. Cristiano Ronaldo being sent off against Barcelona.

So my question is, when teams appeal for a review of a sending off, do the reviewing bodies just look at the particular instance leading to the send off or the whole match behavior before deciding if the bans should be upheld or not?

Comment: I'm really confused by the premise of this question. If a player is sent-off or otherwise cited for committing an offence, and can prove that they did not commit that offence, why would other unrelated incidents in the match have any impact on whether they committed that offence? No sport or legal jurisdiction works like that, as it's a nonsensical proposition.

Comment: @studro My question arose due to more or less same confusion. I had mentioned this in the question earlier, but in my opininion, the exact instances in both the mentioned cases when the red was shown did not warrant a sending-off. 
In Ramos's case particularly, there was an earlier incident in which if he was sent off that would be justified. He got away at that point but was nonetheless shown a red at last.

That got me questioning if the previous incident was in minds of the reviewing body for rejecting the appeal against the ban.

Comment: They both received a second caution in the same match. That's why the appeal failed - the only way to prove that the send-off was invalid is to prove that they didn't receive two cautions. As a general rule, appeals panels / committees don't deal with cautionable offences - only sending-off offences. Allowing the post-match review of cautions would make the workload of appeals committees unmanageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing bodies, in case of Spanish League, Spanish football federation’s (RFEF) compeetition committee and appeals committee, *will only look at the particular instance leading to the sending off or the incident club is appealing against*, and the club has to provide written report with video evidences to that particular incident. Consequences will only be overridden in case of [obvious mistake](https://playtheadvantage.com/2014/02/07/what-a-red-card-appeal-really-means-part-two/).

From [RFEF Disciplinary code](http://www.rfef.es/normativas-sanciones/normativas/c%C3%B3digo-disciplinario):

> Article 130. Review of arbitration decisions.(google translation)
> 2. The disciplinary consequences of such expulsion may be overridden by the disciplinary body only in the event of manifest material error.

---

(As OP was interested in incident involving Sergio Ramos and Ronaldo)

1.For incident involving Ramos <sup>[ESPN](http://www.espn.in/football/real-madrid/story/3186718/real-madrid-captain-sergio-ramos-appeal-against-dismissal-rejected)</sup>: Madrid appealed the second yellow shown by referee Jose Luis Gonzalez Gonzalez, but [the Spanish federation's competition committee](http://cdn1.sefutbol.com/sites/default/files/sanciones/resoluciones_primera_div._j_1.pdf) said the video evidence presented by the club's legal team had failed to establish that the official had made a mistake. Adding, this appeal may be lodged against the Appeal Committee within a maximum period of ten working days.

2.For [incident involving Ronaldo](http://www.hindustantimes.com/football/cristiano-ronaldo-s-appeal-against-5-game-ban-for-pushing-referee-rejected/story-DAK3I6XHovsnLVxselOmuM.html) <sup>[DailyMail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4789284/Cristiano-Ronaldo-given-five-match-ban-pushing-referee.html)</sup>: The Spanish football federation’s (RFEF) appeals committee “dismissed the appeal presented by Real Madrid”, the RFEF said in a statement.

While the [RFEF compeetition committee](http://www.espn.in/football/real-madrid/story/3179565/cristiano-ronaldo-hit-with-five-match-ban-for-red-card-pushing-referee) stated Madrid have 10 days to lodge an appeal with its appeals committee, while adding in its report that the club attempted to get the offence downgraded from a push to a minor "disregard" for the referee.

The [official match report](http://actas.rfef.es/actas/RFEF_CmpActa2?cod_primaria=1000144&CodActa=42775) sent to the RFEF from the Camp Nou included Ronaldo's push in the "other incidents" section.

> Other incidents: (Player: Cristiano Ronaldo Dos Santos Aveiro) Once the red card was shown, the player pushed me slightly in a sign of disagreement.

From [efe.com](https://www.efe.com/efe/english/destacada/spanish-federation-hands-5-match-ban-on-cristiano-ronaldo-for-pushing-referee/50000261-3351728#):

> The sole judge on the RFEF's Competition Committee, after reviewing Real Madrid's defense statements, first of all made clear that the referee was the only sportive authority during the match and his decisions were irrevocable.
>
> The judge also considered that the player violated article 96 of the disciplinary code, which forbids pushing the referee and imposes bans ranging between 4-12 matches for that action.
>
> The judge dismissed the argument that the shove had been an instinctive response from Ronaldo, as Real Madrid claimed, and instead called it an "unjustified and disproportionate reaction."

Other Articles: [mls soccer](http://pressbox.mlssoccer.com/content/appeal-review-red-card-decision), [theguardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2002/sep/24/newsstory.sport8), playtheadvantage [1](https://playtheadvantage.com/2014/02/06/what-a-red-card-appeal-really-means-part-one/) [2](https://playtheadvantage.com/2014/02/07/what-a-red-card-appeal-really-means-part-two/), [theguardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2013/jan/14/manchester-city-appeal-vincent-kompany-red) [2](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2015/sep/22/arsenal-gabriel-paulista-wins-appeal-red-card-chelsea), [espn](http://www.espn.in/football/barcelona/story/3108303/spain-fa-uphold-neymar-three-match-ban-after-barcelona-appeal), [telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/football/2016/12/20/jamie-vardy-loses-appeal-against-red-card-will-miss-leicester/), [bleacherreport](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2287913-lionel-messi-yellow-card-appeal-rejected-by-spanish-federation)